# How to generate a synthetic data similar to the real image

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, makehuman

I have a real image and I need to generate a synthetic image that is very similar in term of shape (I do not need to be very detailed). I am wondering how someone can do this using makehuman and blender. The background is not important. I want just to synthesize the person. Here is an example.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic answer for such a broad question...

Since you say detail doesn't quite matter, you may find something like this interesting. for this approach I used meta spheres, and then  converted it over to a mesh.

Just so I steer clear of any trouble, here are is my source of the image used:
[Pixabay Image Reference](https://pixabay.com/en/entrepreneur-startup-start-up-man-593359/)

Here are the results, and the Blend File:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Blend File:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It is an interesting answer! Could you put more details how did you do it ?

Comment: Yeah would like to see a tutorial video on that surely there should be interest in making a low res model from a photograph.

Comment: It might have to wait until I can put some Blender time in, but once I do, I'll get it on YouTube, and post the link back here in the comments.

Comment: Grrr. So frustrated, I tried screen capturing, but for some reason my video capture stopped working. I'm going to have to see if I can get on another machine to make this happen - Sorry.

Comment: Woohoo - I got my screen capture finally working - [You Tube](https://www.youtube.com/watch)