# How to model into a 2d image?

Tags: modeling, lighting, 2d

Ive been trying to figure out how one would start doing something like [this](https://www.itsnicethat.com/system/files/102019/5db814d77fa44cc59e00143b/images_slice_large/obby-and-jappari-graphic-design-itsnicethat-6.jpg?1572345616)

If you didnt have a 3d scan of the model to work around, but only a 2d image of the person, how would you estimate distances etc? Is it all just moving things until it looks right?

And for shadows, I guess youd use a hidden plane as a shadow catcher, and angle it in such a way that it copies vaguely the shape/angle of the 2d image/person?

Thanks in advance

Comment: After looking around BSE, I found this answer to look something along the lines of what you are trying to accomplish... Maybe try: [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47662/how-to-generate-a-synthetic-data-similar-to-the-real-image/47664#47664)

Comment: This is useful, however one would still have to assume the general geometry while creating a mesh out of metaballs. Its more like modelling a basic human using a 2d image as your reference.

Im not sure what exactly I expect to find as a workaround, but perhaps an addon or software that helps estimate distances without me having to model the parts.

Comment: You will have to replicate the basic shapes of the subject which should be affected by the 3D objects through lighting. [Related answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/140477/30849). If you have geometry guides, you can use fSpy or other addons to estimate the camera properties. Otherwise you have to eyeball it as you suggested. You don't have to create a perfect copy, using image manipulation software shadow and reflections can be warped, added, reduced untill it "looks good".

Comment: [maybe this then](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49033/mesh-reconstruction-using-tracking-data), it has some links in the answers.

Comment: [Please provide some context and explanation, don't just post a link](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this) Also use a descriptive title